# how to convert JSON to Value-Key Pair using PHP or JS?

Tags: php, json, search, key-value

I want to Convert the JSON file to key:value pair, means

```
    [
     {"value":"apple","label":"apple"},
     {"value":"Google","label":"Google"}
    ]
```

Like below ***key:value*** pair format, like this

```
{
"apple": "apple",
"google": "google",
    .......
    .....
    ......
    ......
 }
```

So any one can tell me how can i do so, below is the Php file code, in which i have taken the data from the psql database and storing it in a file .

*dbconn.php*

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres       user=postgres password=root123");
 pg_select($db, 'post_log', $_POST); //selecting database


   $query=pg_query("SELECT name FROM account");
 $json=array();

    while($student=pg_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $student["name"],
                    'label'=>$student["name"]);
    }


$textval = json_encode($json);  //encoding
file_put_contents('textvalues.txt', $textval);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a single object with key/value pairs use the following simple approach:

```
...
while ($student = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
    $json[$student["name"]] = $student["name"];
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks Roman , you solved my problem, one last thing how can i append the result , in a text file file after     var data =    {"apple":"apple","Google":"Google", . . . . . . . . . . . . } "

Comment: use `file_put_contents('textvalues.txt', $textval, FILE_APPEND)`  to append the data to the file instead of overwriting it

Comment: thanks, but when i re-run the file again , it gets appended with the previous data . So how to flush the previous changes as the file gets refresh

Comment: @MDShahrouq, well, your initial approach `file_put_contents('textvalues.txt', $textval);` will work if you need to overwrite the file

Comment: Ya thanks , it worked. I used like this   $foo = "var countries=" . $textval;

Answer (score 1):

Do it in this way (in the `foreach`):

```
    $obj = new stdClass(); 
    $obj->label=1; 
    $obj->value=2;
    $json[]=$obj;

    $obj = new stdClass(); 
    $obj->label=3; 
    $obj->value=4;
    $json[]=$obj;

    print_r(json_encode($json));
```

Result `[{"label":1,"value":2},{"label":3,"value":4}]`

or for only one object

```
    $obj = new stdClass();

    $array = [['name'=>'test'],['name'=>'foo']];

    foreach($array as $var)
      $obj->{$var['name']}=$var['name']; 

    print_r(json_encode($obj));
```

Result `{"test":"test","foo":"foo"}`

Note: I use `stdClass` here, so everbody can see directly what it will become in json (an object too) and should not used with index keys.  `print_r(json_encode([1,'foo'=>'sadsd']));` will become `{"0":1,"foo":"sadsd"}`, what isnt that nice.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the while loop

```
while($student=pg_fetch_array($query)){
$student_name=$student['name'];
$res[$student_name] =$student_name;
 array_push($json,$res);
 }
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

This will return a json string in this format:

```
[{"xyz":"xyz"},{"abc":"abc"}]
```